# Google App Engine Datastore 60-second query limit – how to overcome and why it is not limited in the remote_api_shell

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When I run a query for a lot of entities, like:

```
for e in EntityKind.query(ancestor=some_ancestor).filter(EntityKind.some_attribute == 'some_value'):
    print e.key
```

it times out after 60 seconds, with this message: `The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable`. (I run this on a task queue, so the request timeout limit is 10 minutes, so this should not be a problem)

However, strangely if I run the above code in the `remote_api_shell.py`, the query runs continuously, even though it starts to slow down after several minutes.

How could they be different?

Comment: I assume if you use cursors it doesnt happen?

Comment: Yes, using cursors it can run over the 60 sec limit.

Comment: any reason why not use cursors? i assume trying to get all on a single call is not a good practice for scale as it would also consume more ram?

Comment: Simpler coding without using cursor. What I mean is,  if in the remote api shell, the query can run indefinitely, why the need of using cursors in the application code?

Comment: tbh haven't used that shell but i assume since it runs locally it doesnt affect the plattform. once running in cloud google doesnt like having processes that would take too long to fetch results or consume too much ram (to buffer and later hold results) those dont scale well so google puts the 60sec limit to force you to use a method that does scale.